# How to convert ReportDataV2 records to use XML format?

Tags: xtrareport

I have ReportDataV2 records in a table and I want to convert them to support

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.ReportsV2;
using DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EF;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;
 
 
namespace MyFunctions;

public class HandyReportFunctions
{
    public static void ConvertReport(ReportDataV2 report)
    {
        var xtraRep = ReportDataProvider.ReportsStorage.LoadReport(report);
        // errors with Deserialization from CodeDOM format is not supported in .NET Core applications
    }
```

From this [ticket](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t691887/converting-xtrareport-reports-from-codedom-to-xml) I see I need to use XtraReport.SaveLayoutToXml but that works with files. I am loading from a database

[Update]

Using the old framework  I can export to an XML Repx
[image: Export Layout]

I tried exporting to a file and then importing but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to export to xml Repx from the old program and import to a new ReportDataV2 record in the new program.